# Methods from Partial Class

Tags: t4, partial-classes, tangible-t4-editor

I'm using the tangible `T4` example from the documentation and pull the classes as followed:

```
// get all class items from the code model
var allClasses = VisualStudioHelper.CodeModel.GetAllCodeElementsOfType(project.CodeModel.CodeElements, EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass, false);
```

And the methods:

```
// get all methods implemented by this class
var allFunctions = VisualStudioHelper.CodeModel.GetAllCodeElementsOfType(codeClass.Members, EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction, false);
```

Here is how I initialize project and codeClass:

```
var project = VisualStudioHelper.GetProject("CodeBase");
var allClasses = VisualStudioHelper.CodeModel.GetAllCodeElementsOfType(project.CodeModel.CodeElem‌​ents, EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass, false); 

foreach(CodeClass codeClass in allClasses) { ..... }
```

This works except that I don't get all methods from the `class`. The class is a `partial class` and I only get the methods from the 1st `*.cs` file.

Any idea or workaround?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Very helpful. I still don't know the answer to my question, but at least I got lectured on tags in message headers.

Comment: Can you show your code where you initialize `project` and `codeClass`?

Comment: Here is how I initialize project and codeClass:

var project = VisualStudioHelper.GetProject("CodeBase");
var allClasses = VisualStudioHelper.CodeModel.GetAllCodeElementsOfType(project.CodeModel.CodeElements, EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass, false);

foreach(CodeClass codeClass in allClasses)
{
.....
}

Comment: @CSharpDummy could you possibly insert the relevant code to the question itself - placing code in comments is somehow cumbersome to read.

Comment: I can actually reproduce this very issue: https://gist.github.com/dittodhole/2bdef7fb74d47bd7cac7 - I strongly believe this is a bug. Alternatively you could try iterating the project's items and build your tree based on items ... :/ meh

Comment: Ok I'll send them an email.